# How Do I Read & Write Binary Files In C#?

Tags: c#, binary

I'm trying to write an app in C# that will write data to a binary file and then read it. The problem is that when I try to read it, the app crashes with the error "Unable to read beyond the end of the stream."

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Read_And_Write_To_Binary
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog SaveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            SaveFileDialog.Title = "Save As...";
            SaveFileDialog.Filter = "Binary File (*.bin)|*.bin";
            SaveFileDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
            if (SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(SaveFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Create);
                // Create the writer for data.
                BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);

                string Name = Convert.ToString(txtName.Text);
                int Age = Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text);
                bw.Write(Name);
                bw.Write(Age);

                fs.Close();
                bw.Close();
            }
         }

        private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog OpenFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            OpenFileDialog.Title = "Open File...";
            OpenFileDialog.Filter = "Binary File (*.bin)|*.bin";
            OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
            if (OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(OpenFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Create);
                BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

                lblName.Text = br.ReadString();
                lblAge.Text = br.ReadInt32();

                fs.Close();
                br.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use FileMode.Create in the code that reads the file.  That destroys it.  You want FileMode.Open of course.

Answer (score 4):

You're using `FileMode.Create` for reading the file.

You should use `FileMode.Open` instead.

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(SaveFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Open);
```

When you open the stream for creating a file, the existing file will be rewritten, so you'll get this exception as there is no data available in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `FileMode.Create` when reading the file, use `FileMode.Open`.  From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode.aspx) for `FileMode.Create` (emphasis mine):

> Specifies that the operating system should create a new file. **If the file already exists, it will be overwritten.** ... FileMode.Create is equivalent to requesting that if the file does not exist, use CreateNew; otherwise, use Truncate.

And Truncate, as its name implies, truncates the file to be zero bytes long:

> Specifies that the operating system should open an existing file. When the file is opened, it should be truncated so that its size is zero bytes.